# Get percentage value of GROUP BY results in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I'm working with survey data. Essentially, I want to count total responses for a question for a location, then use that total to create what percentage of all responses each particular response is. I then want to group results by location.

An ideal output would be similar to this:

> Q1 | State | City | %
>
> yes| MA    | bos |10
>
> no | MA    | bos |40
>
> m. | MA    | bos |50
>
> yes| MA    | cam |20
>
> no | MA    | cam |20
>
> m. | MA    | cam |80

The problem I run into (I believe) is that `GROUP BY` works before my `count` statement, so I can't count all the responses. Below is an example of what I have to produce real numbers:

```
SELECT q1, state, city, COUNT(q1) FROM master GROUP BY state, city, q1
```

Not all questions have responses, so below is my attempt to get the percentage:

```
SELECT q1, state, city, count(q1)/(count(nullif(q1,0))) as percent FROM master group by state, city, q1
```

I believe using `WITH` or `OVER(PARTITION BY...)` would be a possible avenue, but I can't get either to work.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the query needs to be phrased in two parts. One to get the count per State+City plus another to get the count per State+City+Q1. You then join these two queries together and do the calculation on the combined results. There might be a more elegant solution than this, but something along these lines perhaps might work. Apologies for any typos!

```
select t1.q1, t1.state, t1.city, ResponseCount, 100.0 * ResponseCount/CityCount as "%"
from
   (select q1, state, city, count(q1) as ResponseCount
    from master
    group by state, city, q1) t1
 join
   (select state, city, count(*) as CityCount
    from master
    group by state, city) t2
 on t2.State = t1.State and t2.City = t1.City
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
GROUP BY state, city, COUNT(q1)
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  If I group by count(q1), I don't think that will help me get the total responses per question, to then use against the count(q1).  Instead of count(q1) I want count(q1)/total_responses_per_this_location, or something like that.  or am I complicating things?

Comment: That would be two separate aggregates over a different selection criteria, which is what Trevor answered.